# How to create a link to a custom wordpress theme page?

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created four custom child pages on Wordpress (Custom theme) to parent page:

Parent:

- Drawings.php

Child links:

- Other.php
- More.php
- Paintings.php
- Events.php

The pages are shown in the browser by these urls:

- http://localhost:8000/drawings/other/
- http://localhost:8000/drawings/more/
- http://localhost:8000/drawings/paintings/
- http://localhost:8000/drawings/events/

How can I create four links in my parent page (http://localhost:8000/drawings) that links to those child links?

I tried linking simply by url, like so:

```
<a class="link-1" href="http://localhost:8000/drawings/more/">| More |</a>
```

But I get an error: `Page not found`

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried: `<?php echo get_home_url() . '/drawings/more/'; ?>`
Pretty sure it should be working... gl.